# Having trouble with Accordian for website

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla

I'm not sure if the problem is with the code or how I am implementing it. I am working in Joomla! and am trying to add an accordion to one of my pages using a template I got from http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol. The code uses html, css, and javascript and the problem seems to be with the javascript. The accordian looks like it should, but does not open to show the content within. Below is the code.

CSS:

```
<style>
button.accordion {
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
content: '\002B';
color: #777;
font-weight: bold;
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
background-color: white;
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
opacity: 1;
max-height: 500px;  
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user         clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}
}
</script>
```

I've followed all instructions on how to implement javascript into Joomla! but am still having trouble. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine in the snippet. How are you adding the javascript to Joomla?

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
content: '\002B';
color: #777;
font-weight: bold;
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
background-color: white;
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
opacity: 1;
max-height: 500px;  
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user         clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I followed the steps in this advice article: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/custom-js/

Comment: Using the following link try using one of the three methods and see if your js starts working. https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript